# Change the color of scrollbar with Javascript "vanilla"

Tags: javascript

I want to change style of scroll bar without using one of the many jquery plugins, but with the best Javascript Framework, "Vanilla JS". Any examples (cross browser)? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Those jQuery plugins just make scrollbars out of HTML elements. Read the source code of one plugin if you want to know how it's done.

Comment: Why?  No-one likes colored scrollbars.

Comment: jarmod only for example, to know where to begin to change the scroll bar :)

Comment: You need to make your own if you need it to work outside of WebKit. That is just how it's done. @jarmod, Google use them to great effect, and there are good reasons for doing that, beyond just polishing an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the color of the scrollbar "vanilla" has more to do with CSS. Webkit provides selectors for it but I don't think a cross-browser solution exists:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

Comment: This is not cross-platform :/